In Windows 11, how to create a log of all the commands executed by cmd.exe?
I need to have a persistent log/history file for cmd.exe on windows which shows all the commands executed through cmd.exe. It does not matter it was directly opened through the "start" menu or called through a Python script.
What change shall I make so that all future commands that are executed through cmd.exe, irrespective of how it called, are logged in a file.

Does the answer in How to tell what command were executed by cmd.exe pop up? do what you want?

@ChesterGillon Hello, thank you for you comment. I am trying to digest all the information in the link that you shared. It seems it logs the details like time, process etc. It is not very clear if I can the commands that were executed. I am checking, I will update after some time.

group policy is not working in the windows version that I have, it will take some time to fix it.

Following the links to the Microsoft documentation in the above referenced answer, event ID 4688(S): A new process has been created. (Windows 10) is logged. There is the option, enabled by group policy, to log Process Command Line which should give the command (he name of executable and arguments which were passed to it) which was executed.

This question is similar to: How to tell what command were executed by cmd.exe pop up?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ChesterGillon it does not work at all for me. Maybe I am still not figured out how to do it, but I tried my best to follow the instructions. I think the linked answer only add logs when the user logs in. I need something which works 24 hours a day.

@DrMoishePippik I already followed the instructions in the linked answer but it does not help me at all. The suggested solution only works for when the user logs in and not throughout the day.

Would Sysmon help record what you want?  This would record all the processes creation events which includes the parent (pid, path). So you could filter down to processes created where the parent is cmd.exe, powershell.exe, etc..  This will include the user and other info like the command line.  Might be of use.

https://pastebin.com/raw/ti8VrQCQ is a simple option to extract the data where cmd.exe is the parent.  You can increase the max size of the sysmon event log as required.

Use clink that preserves the history of commands and is generally recommended to adjust cmd to current shell standards.
You can check saved commands with e.g.:
clink history

or in clink_history file. You can even preserve history across all sessions by enabling history.shared setting:
clink set history.shared true

See docs for more info.
